# Selenium - Do not scroll element into view

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mousehover

Using selenium webdriver, I'm trying to find web elements that are fully in view (and those that are partially in view). When one hovers over these elements, they will enlarge, displaying additional information (which I want to verify).

However, when I go to hover over these elements, selenium will auto-scroll the frame to put the whole element in view.

I do not want this to happen, as by scrolling the frame, it causes other items to go out of view and some items to come into view (which defeats the purpose of my test, which is testing only the items that are in full and partial view of the original frame).

I've tried using Robot to move the mouse to specified coordinates. Robot successfully does this, however I'm not able to pull the information I need to verify once the elements enlarge (not sure why).

I've also tried using Actions, Javascript, mouse.MouseMove resulting in no success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change this behaviour. It's designed to scroll to the view when you target a particular element.